# Is it possible to run Appium iOS automated tests on Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, linux, ubuntu, appium

I know that it's impossible to code the test on ubuntu since I need apple's xCode, but I would like to know if, once coded, it is possible to run the automated tests on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, appium needs xCode to use UiAutomation and instruments to perform testing on iOS unfortunately.

Comment: Is this still true for the newest versions of Appium?

Comment: https://bartsaintgermain.medium.com/ios-automation-on-linux-using-appium-f35bc14e86eb shows how you can execute your iOS tests on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I did follow with success the following tutorial: [Appium on Raspberry-Pi](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/tutorials/appium-on-raspberrypi/)

My current setup is as follows:

- iOS devices connected to Raspberry-Pi 4 (Ubuntu)
- Appium server on RPi + Quamotion tools
- Inspect/Run automation scripts from remote computer.

I tried this on RPi but I guess this works on any Ubuntu computer/server.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)