# Can i use Appium to test IOS and Android on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

Is there a way to automate mobile application testing on ubuntu with Appium to test IOS and Android ? Or we are always obliged to test with Mac.
Or is there another tool that we can generate scripts with recorder that works on ubuntu ?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Appium iOS automated tests on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529495/is-it-possible-to-run-appium-ios-automated-tests-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run the Appium iOS test , we need to some xcode to be installed on machine. I don't think so you can install xcode in Ubuntu.

Reason behind is :

Appium use xcode uiautomator to run the test in real device / simulator.

Still you want to run appium iOS test Ubuntu, you may ended with extra work like install VM and install MAC os in that VM so on.

Comment: ah ok, just i'm asking to know if there is a possible way without Mac.

Comment: @Priya please checkout this video , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_xHmofGgUE, if you need more please subscribe my channel here : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaJA59vxBDS7smS81Gqf7KA

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. As @mani points out, Appium iOS test requires some xcode components but there exists packages which replace those components on Ubuntu.

There is a nice tutorial on [Appium on linux](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/tutorials/appium-on-raspberrypi/) which helps to install those.

Comment: We did write an article on https://bartsaintgermain.medium.com/ios-automation-on-linux-using-appium-f35bc14e86eb