# How to setup or can we setup appium on ubuntu for ios?

Tags: ios, automation, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I want perform automation testing on IOS and Android app on ubuntu using Appium. I am new to this. Can we perform automation of IOS application on ubuntu ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Appium iOS automated tests on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529495/is-it-possible-to-run-appium-ios-automated-tests-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

**You can set up Appium on ubuntu for Android only**. For iOS app testing using appium, the primary requirement is XCode which comes with only iOS Operating System which you can get only on MacBook/MacMini. However, you can set up on ubuntu for Android.

Comment: could you please suggest any techstack that I can user to perform automaton testing on ubuntu ?

Comment: For iOS App testing using any tool, Xcode is must, which only comes with MacBook/MacMini.

Comment: There exists a possibility to run it on Linux: https://bartsaintgermain.medium.com/ios-automation-on-linux-using-appium-f35bc14e86eb

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the techstack of quamotion. They provide the necessary stubs for the required tools on ubuntu.

You can follow a tutorial on http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/tutorials/appium-on-raspberrypi/