# Can we test ios application using appium in Ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, ubuntu-16.04, appium-ios

I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit. Can we test/automate ios application using appium in Ubuntu? Also please help to install appium in ubuntu as i am new to this and i tried but couldn't installed appium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Appium iOS automated tests on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529495/is-it-possible-to-run-appium-ios-automated-tests-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

**No,**

To test iOS applications, you need to have Mac. You can however install MacOS by [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-macOS-on-a-Windows-PC) or various other methods available on internet. You can also connect to a Remote Sever running on a Mac from your PC.

Comment: is this answer still valid?

Comment: As far as I know, yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to test iOS applications using Appium on Ubuntu, if you're willing to use 3rd party, commercial software.

Various companies offer such utilities:

- [Microfocus Mobile Center](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/uft-mobile/overview) allows you to run Appium-based tests on iOS devices on Ubuntu
- Quamotion offers a Docker image, [quamotion/appium-docker-ios](https://github.com/quamotion/appium-docker-ios), which you can use to use Appium to test iOS devices on Ubuntu.